# EF6 Extending ASPNET Identity to include additional entities via 'model first'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

The scenario:

1. Fire up VS 2013, create a ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity project (Individual User Accounts)
2. I need to model the rest of the application, so I create an 'Entity model' .edmx diagram and proceed to add new entities - in keeping with 'Model first' paradigm;

The problem:

1. How do I get ASPNET identity tables in the same model diagram?
2. Can I add new fields to the ASPNETUser entity in the model itself..will that break ASPNET identity?

Comment: I had considerable pain trying to do `model-first` with EF6 and asp.net identity. In the end I gave up and used `code-first` and the `database migration` command line options to update my database. That let me add new fields to the identity classes and migrate them to my Azure database.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, TrueBlueAussie. I am surprised at the implementation of ASPNET identity and it's tight coupling with the Entity framework. Why do I need to care about migrations when I have barely started developing my App?

Comment: I agree and was also annoyed with it. I am also surprised that, after so many iterations, Microsoft still can't name their columns to any sort of consistent standard (`UserId` and `User_id` being the most annoying one in the latest version).

Comment: Any new ideas on this? I was thinking of making my model  first, then generate the code and extend the user class with IdentityUser and make the database.